# Customization of columns in jenkins form for specific JOB

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there any way in Jenkins where I can view customized data for a specific project. Like in the screenshot we can see columns (Salves, Online slaves, offline slaves etc.)  [Screen shot Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnTCy.png)
View> Edit View> Portlets in the right column > Slaves statistics

I want to customize these columns for my project requirements like Build numbers, Revision numbers, svn changes (for every individual revision), the user (who submit this build) and Status. I knew we can see these changes individually from **localhost:8080/jenkins/job/Job_name/224/** but I want to see whole information in one single form. I am good in Powershell but Java is not my cup of tea. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a plugin available to add custom columns, will require creating a custom plugin yourself. A plugin to add some pre-defined extra columns is available https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Extra+Columns+Plugin

Alternatively, we added custom key value pairs in every build using `currentBuild.description` as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNo1M.png) to be able to view in a single screen artifact name and environment for each build